# How to submit app with cocoapods to iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm at the last step of submitting my app to the app store but I'm getting these errors for each cocoapod that I used in my project. Am I supposed to include them in the archive or change the bundle identifier for each of them to my app's bundle ID. I searched all over and can't find a guide on how to submit an app with cocoapods. I presumed it's really straightforward. Please help!

**[Error Message]** 
No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier `org.cocoapods.CocoaLumberjack` is correct.

[image]

Comment: Log on to iTunes Connect -> Click the plus symbol -> New App -> Supply that bundle id and name -> Good to go

Comment: @TommyDevoy Sorry, I'm still confused. The bundle id in the error is not my app's bundle id. It's generated by cocoapod during pod install. Should I override it with my app's bundle id?

Comment: I think while archieving, you have selected a pod instead of the main project target. Also make sure the  app is created in itunes connect with the project Bundle identifier.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem, with cocoapods

Answer (score 2):

It works after I set the following attributes in my Info.plist.

```
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
```

That's "Bundle OS Type code". Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect... i have the same problem as above.. Solved